# redefine javascript method body

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

i have a jquery dialog which is defined like this (part of the code shown here)

```
 buttons: {
                    "Opslaan": function() {
                        Opslaan();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Annuleren": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
```

De `Opslaan()` function is defined with an empty body (`function Opslaan(){}`).

Now the dialog is opened from various places, so i want, when the dialog is opened, to define the body of the `Opslaan()` method because it has to save the data in the dialog, but that gets injected at those various place, so the Opslaan (Save) method must me different all the time.

One thing i thought of was to pass the actual method to the dialog when i open it (so to replace the static `opslaan();` call with the passed method) , but i don't know if that is possible

So in pseudo code when a user clicks button A

- get html for dialog
- redefine method A (put the right javascript in the body OR let the Opslaan method point to method OpslaanA()
- open the dialog

Comment: what does ` body (function Opslaan(){})` do ?

Comment: the dialog gets injected with some textboxes. The dialog is used for 4 different little crud screens. Then, when the user clicks Opslaan (means 'save') it has to call the right Save method in order to parse the injected html because the html is different in all 4 cases. So the Opslaan method looks at the html in de dialog and gets the values from the textboxes en creates a webservice call of it. So when you click the button 'Opslaan' i want to call different implementations of that method depending of the injected html in de dialog. That answers your question?

Comment: ok, well I think you have 4 different opslaan methods on each page right? that has different instructions? in that case check that window.Opslaan exists first or that it is on your dom before a user has to click the button, I don't know why you can't use `serialize()` method to pass your post/get data hope that helps some how if not, place some sample codes for each page or how it works in codes :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing the unique function in as the argument for the generic function is a great way to handle this.  Here's a simple demo:

```
var save = function(saveFunction) {
    saveFunction();

    // common code 
    alert('common code');
}

var aSaveFunction = function() {
    alert('aSaveFunction Called.');
};

$('#one').click(function() {
    save(aSaveFunction);
});

var aDifferentSaveFunction = function() {
    alert('aDifferentSaveFunction Called.');
};

$('#two').click(function() {
    save(aDifferentSaveFunction);
});
```

Or see the fiddle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/7H3mm/3/

Also, for more on javascript functions as objects: http://www.sergiopereira.com/articles/advjs.html, look for, "What do you mean? A function is an object too?".